# Where do Console.Writeline messages of a DLL go?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using a DLL (whose code I can see also) that uses `Console.WriteLine` to write messages.

I am using it from a console application in which I use Trace.Writeline. If I eliminate the console (by making it a Windows application in the output of the Properties) where do these DLL console messages go?

Right now I am redirecting my Trace messages to go to a file even when running the release version. Is there a way to do something similar to the dll console messages?

And if not, if I put Trace messages in the DLL and recompile, are they also going to be redirected?

Comment: The DLL becomes part of the whole.

Comment: The Standart Output of just goes to nowhere. It is possible to attach a Console Window to a non-console App, using the unmanaged Windows API: http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/ It is also possible to redirect the output of any programm you start via the Process class. And sometimes processes need to restart themself to make certain that specific rights or other conditions are met.